# Migrating closed, off-topic, on-hold questions (past, present, and future) to more appropriate SE sites

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, migration

I had the intent of finding better SE sites for my questions that were closed, put on hold, or off-topic. I flagged a moderator for one of my questions, but I don't think an action was taken (if there was, I would not know how I would be informed). This led me to think about all of the other questions out there that are not a fit for the workplace, but would be better suited for another site.

*Should such questions, at either request of the question asker or the discretion of a moderator, simply migrate questions instead of having them closed?*

Comment: did you ask folks at these other sites (in chat or meta) whether they want them moved there or not? Also please keep in mind that after 60 days system doesn't let migrate

Comment: no, but I should. I only based off of the help center FAQ

Comment: You should be able to see any moderator comments on your flags from your personal flag page. You can reach it from the "### helpful flags" link on your user profile, below your "impact". [This](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/38289) should be your URL. What you should be able to see there is: "*Given the age of the question and the likelihood of it being ill-received in its current state (too long, possibly off-topic) we can't migrate it. Best to ask a new question on PM.SE instead.*"

Comment: Ahh, thank you for the clarification. I didn’t know that I can see the messages.

Comment: And don't forget the [golden rule of migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/260884).

Answer (score 5):

I'm speaking as an individual moderator, not for the team.  (I'm not saying I think they'd disagree; we haven't talked about it.)

First, there's a time limit on migrations: questions older than 60 days can't be migrated.  So there's nothing we can do about questions that old no matter how clear the case is otherwise.

Second, if the question might be on-topic somewhere else *but* it's poorly asked, missing important information, hard to understand... the other site would just put it on hold anyway, bouncing it back to us, so we're not going to migrate that.

Third, if a question already has a bunch of good answers here, it shouldn't be migrated.  That's not fair to the people who answered *here*, and it's not fair to the other site (which now has to curate answers that might not meet *their* rules even though they met *ours*).  In this case we should close the question here and advise the OP to re-ask the question on the other site, linking the current question for background.

If the question is well-asked and unanswered and the OP is an experienced SE user and actively engaged in the question, it's probably faster for the OP to re-ask the question himself instead of waiting for a moderator to see a flag.  But if the OP asks for migration anyway and it seems like a reasonable destination I'll generally honor that; after all, I'm not doing anything he couldn't have done himself.

We can ask for more migration options in the close dialogue.  SE generally avoids setting up migration paths to young beta sites; they're trying to find their way and it's better if they do it organically, not by being flooded with stuff from other sites.  I would want to see buy-in from IPS for a migration path from here, and they would probably want to see a list of closed Workplace questions that our community thinks belong on IPS, so they can decide how much they trust our judgement.

---

In my personal opinion, migration is pretty broken in a lot of ways, some technical and some behavioral.  I'd like to see SE eliminate migration entirely, replacing it with [a way to help the OP manage his question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285471/162102).

Answer (score 2):

> should such questions, at either request of the question asker or the discretion of a moderator, simply migrate questions instead of having them closed?

Surely a mod can do the migration at will, but I doubt they do that lightly or "just because" OP requested it.

As far as I know, a way to justify a migration is for the question to be closed as off-topic for *"belonging to other site"*. This can be done via `Closing > Off-Topic > Migration` ...

...which, surprise!, is pretty useless here on TWP as we have [no more options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration) for sites to flag as migration targets (that's a [status-declined](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) so I won't get my hopes too high). There was also a ["more recent"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160929/add-flag-as-other-checkbox-to-vote-to-close-as-off-topic-dialog) follow-up request asked (about 5 years ago), but no clear actions to be seen for this.

What I see folks do here on TWP is to **flag with `Closing > Off-Topic > Other` and link on their comment the SE site they consider more appropriate for this case.** The OP can then ask for the question to be migrated, or some mod can see this and take proper action.

---

Now, what I think is not possible (and that doesn't make much sense either) is to **attempt to migrate a question that was closed for any other reason**:

1. If a question was *company-specific or legal advice* I doubt it can be answered elsewhere but *maybe* here on TWP (but we would probably be guessing) or *maybe* in [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/). This I also doubt as they clearly say that:

   > Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter. These are [off-topic](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice) for Law Stack Exchange.
2. If the question *lacked a goal* or *asked us to make a choice* then the question was indeed Workplace related (thus unlikely, if not impossible to fit in other SE site), but off-topic. Hence no migration.
3. If it was *unclear what the poster was asking* then definitely it's a lost case and no migration required (at least not until it is clarified).
4. If the question was *too broad* or *primarily opinion-based* it was again Workplace material (no other place to migrate) but is not answerable in a clear and objective way, or as specified by the [Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

---

So, bottom line, I think that **what you ask is already actively carried out** by our kind and diligent Moderators ... and with some of our help :).

They currently handle the migrations that take place in TWP, either by their **own judgment**, OP's **justified request**, or well with the outputs from the organic **Closing Process handled by the Community**.

This you have probably seen by now, when we get questions that go to IPS (which seems to be our main migration target) ... did I hear we should add that as migration option?... oh wait, I already explained that part.

Still, I would like to hear what our Mods have to say about this question and my perception of it.

Comment: I feel with the recent [interpersonal skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) stack exchange, that list of other sites should be re-visited. We do seem to be getting a few questions being closed off as being better suited for there

Comment: @Draken I agree with you... but I doubt that happens unless we all ask for it (like we managed the Be Nice post Notice, with lead of IDAIKT, but support and thinking it through from behalf of us all and some time for that to happen). I recall several other sites want/wanted to do so, but ignore how that ended... at least we could use other option there besides the only one we got (Meta TWP, lol)!! :) but yeah, I would guess it's "just" some Query to SEs backend that fills the options of that list, so it should be "easy" to add other option (unless they were hard-coded haha)